# How to get overall rank based on data regardless of scope (all items, user specific, etc.)?

Tags: mysql, rank

Table schemas:

```
servers
- id
- user_id
- game_id
- slug
  ...

server_votes
- id
- server_id
- ip_address
- created_at
  ...
```

So, I have a two tables: `servers` and `server_votes`, and I want to get the rank of each server based on how many votes each server has received in a certain amount of time. I have created the following query to do just that (apart from the ranking part):

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.slug,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(sv.id)
        FROM
            server_votes AS sv
        WHERE
            DATE(sv.created_at) > '2016-01-24 19:11:15'
        AND 
            sv.server_id = s.id
    ) AS votes
FROM
    servers AS s
LEFT JOIN
    server_votes AS sv 
ON 
    sv.server_id = s.id
WHERE 
    s.game_id = 1
GROUP BY
    s.id
ORDER BY 
    votes DESC,
    s.id ASC
```

The query above will return the following:

```
*----*---------*---------*-------*
| id | user_id | slug    | votes |
*----*---------*---------*-------*
| 4  | 1       | Server4 | 3     |
| 2  | 1       | Server2 | 2     |
| 1  | 1       | Server1 | 0     |
| 3  | 2       | Server3 | 0     |
| 5  | 2       | Server5 | 0     |
*----*---------*---------*-------*
```

I'd like to end up with the following:

```
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
| id | user_id | slug    | votes | rank |
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
| 4  | 1       | Server4 | 3     | 1    |
| 2  | 1       | Server2 | 2     | 2    |
| 1  | 1       | Server1 | 0     | 3    |
| 3  | 2       | Server3 | 0     | 4    |
| 5  | 2       | Server5 | 0     | 5    |
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
```

Or if I'm querying a specific user's server's, I'd get the rank in context of all servers:

```
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
| id | user_id | slug    | votes | rank |
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
| 3  | 2       | Server3 | 0     | 4    |
| 5  | 2       | Server5 | 0     | 5    |
*----*---------*---------*-------*------*
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Also, here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eae3/2) incase that is of any help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query uses a variable for ranking:

```
SELECT t.id,
    t.user_id,
    t.slug,
    t.votes,
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.id,
        s.user_id,
        s.slug,
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(sv.id)
            FROM
                server_votes AS sv
            WHERE
                DATE(sv.created_at) > '2016-01-24 19:11:15'
            AND 
                sv.server_id = s.id
        ) AS votes
    FROM
        servers AS s
    LEFT JOIN
        server_votes AS sv 
    ON 
        sv.server_id = s.id
    WHERE 
        s.game_id = 1
    GROUP BY s.id
) t, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY 
    t.votes DESC,
    t.id ASC
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eae3/8/0).

**Output:**

```
id  user_id slug    votes   rank
4   1       Server4 3       1
2   1       Server2 2       2
1   1       Server1 0       3
3   2       Server3 0       4
5   2       Server5 0       5
```

Once the above query is put in a subquery with a WHERE clause, it outputs data for a specific user:

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    r.user_id,
    r.slug,
    r.votes,
    r.rank
FROM (
   ...
) r
WHERE r.user_id = 2;
```

It will output id 3 and 5.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eae3/10/0)